# What does || : mean in the context of a shell script?

Tags: bash

What does `|| :` mean in the context of a shell script?

I just came across this line:

```
eval "/usr/bin/mybinary aparameter" || :
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `||` is an “or” comparison operator.

The [`:`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_003a) is a null operator which does… Nothing. Well, it does return a successful exit status… If you need that?

So in your case:

```
eval "/usr/bin/mybinary aparameter" || :
```

The pseudo-example either `eval`s as true or do… Nothing… But return a successful exit status. It seems silly but it’s all pseudo-code to show you general structure so it does seem to make sense in a way.

Comment: The `:` command has a useful side-effect: it always returns a successful exit status. If the eval exits with an error, the `|| :` will force a zero exit status.

Comment: This seems like another use of the `|| true` idiom, just less readable.

Comment: One use case is if the user wants to create a script using `set -e` to exit immediately upon any error, but does not care about this particular command.

Comment: This is probably useful in any environment where the parent process/wrapper sees any non-zero exit status as a problem, but you don't want it to. For example scripts in a yum package.